# javascript loop not giving expected results

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Okay so I haven't touched JS in a long time, and need a little help with a simple loop. I am building a checkers game. Here is the code so far:

```
checkerboard = [[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
                [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
                [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
                [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
                [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
                [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
                [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
                [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]];
function setSquare(player, row, col) {
    // which places a player (either 'R' or 'B') at a particular row and column on the board.
    checkerboard[row][col] = player;
    return checkerboard[row][col];
}

function getPieceAt(row, col) {
    //returns the piece at a particular row and column if there's no piece at that position, it should return null//
    return checkerboard[row][col] || null;
}


function clearBoard(array){
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        var subArray = i;
        for(var x = 0; x < subArray.length; x++){
           subArray[i][x] = 'hello';
        }
    }

}
```

The clearBoard function does not work.

The function is supposed to revert all the values of the array to null.

Problem: It doesn't seem to be doing *anything* and I don't see whatever it is I am missing. I tried it with a return, returning 'array', but it didn't work so I took it out thinking maybe it was calling the original hardcoded array (checkerboard - full of null values). What's wrong with my loop?

// For the sake of easier testing, I am having it do the opposite for the time being (otherwise I have to keep setting values to something other that null using the setSquare function every time I save and re-run the code, because the environment I am using reverts everything back to original/null. It's tedious.) Once the code can set all the values to "hello", I know it can set them to null. //

Comment: You are setting the subArray variable to i than basically calling `i[i][x] = 'hello'`. That doesn't sound right. I'd venture that's the problem right there

Comment: This is purely a debugging problem. You should have used a debugger or logged this instead of asking on stackoverflow.

Comment: I see what you are saying but I have tried it using `subArray[x] = 'hello'` and that didn't work either :(   so I figured to access the value, it needed to be more specific? how should i be writing that line?

Comment: @HolyMoly See my answer to your problem. You assigned subarray to a number and subarray should only be indexed with one index

Comment: That would probably be a great way to go about it Arvind, but I haven't learned to use debuggers or use logs yet...building a simple chess game is pretty indicative of a newb;) and last i checked SO is for all levels of experience...but thanks!

Comment: then why did you vol7ron??? It's simple enough to bypass questions 'below' your elite coding skills without leaving snarky remarks. Everybody was a newb once upon a time;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i is a number. you are assigning subarray to that number.

```
function clearBoard(array){
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        var subArray = i; // subarray goes 0, 1, 2, 3, ... not an array but a number
        for(var x = 0; x < subArray.length; x++){
            subArray[i][x] = 'hello'; // your indexing too much.
        }
    }
}
```

I think this will work better for you

```
function clearBoard(array){
    var subArray;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        subArray = array[i];
        for(var x = 0; x < subArray.length; x++){
            subArray[x] = null; // this will bring you back to the beginning state
        }
    }
}
```

call it like this.

```
clearBoard(checkerboard);
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! I originally indexed as 'subArray[x]' but it wouldn't work and I thought that was the problem, so i made it worse trying to be more specific- lol....I had a feeling that wasn't right! But what I REALLY wasn't seeing was the var subArray = array[i]....tuh!!!!! of course!!! it was driving  me nuts!!! thanks again :)

Comment: @HolyMoly No problem. A quick tip to see if your indexing is specific enough. You obviously understand that your checkerboard is a 2 dimensional array. Notice that in the function where you are "digging" into it that there are two sets of square brackets [] These should always line up when you are inexing through the values of nested arrays.

Comment: @HolyMoly So you defined a two dimension array `var checkerboard = [[], [], ...]`. You have to "unwrap" the array twice to get to the value i.e. `checkerboard[row][col]` see in the clear board function we are doing this in two steps by having `subarray = array[i]` and we are modifying directly `subarray[x]` notice that we use the square brackets twice? it matches the depth of checkerboard.